# SQLite/ADO.NET- Data Adapter doesn't write correct number of rows to SQLite file

Tags: c#, sqlite, ado.net, dataadapter

Continuing my saga of converting program output from CSV to SQLite, I've run into another problem. I am taking a text file, breaking it up by line and commas, and putting the results of that into a list. I am then following [this](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlitecsharp/dataset/) tutorial on how to use the ADO.NET DataSet and .NET Data Providers to insert data into a table, since my earlier method did not create a table correctly.

The line reader from the file returns that it reads 134 rows, which is the correct number of rows in the file (which, by the way, can be found [here](http://pastebin.com/g6F6cPLq)... you would benefit from using it for testing). Furthermore, the DataTable object created for loading the data into the data adapter also reads a total of 134 rows. However, when the time comes to open the file and see what's in it (which I've been doing using wxSQLite+), the rows are not all there. The number of rows written varies, but it's inevitably not 134. Furthermore, the data types applied across the rows is not uniform. The data fields in odd-numbered rows stay true to the schema I entered when the table was created, but even-numbered rows suffer a conversion of all integer-type rows to double. I'm not quite sure what's causing this, and have deviated from the tutorial's code a bit, but the principle should still be the same. It could be something simple and stupid (I'm **wonderful** at making those mistakes), but my Ph.D student supervisor couldn't see anything glaringly wrong with the implementation.

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SQLite;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace C_Sharp_SQLite_Testbed{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for MainWindow.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class MainWindow : Window{
        private static string fileName;
        private static string dataName;
        public static string[] lines; 
        public MainWindow(){
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
            //open input file
            string dateTime = DateTime.Today.ToString("dd_mm_yyyy");
            Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog dlg = new Microsoft.Win32.OpenFileDialog();
            dlg.FileName = "Document";
            dlg.DefaultExt = ".txt";
            dlg.Filter = "Text Documents (.txt)|*.txt";
            
            Nullable<bool> result = dlg.ShowDialog();
            string inputFilePath = dlg.FileName;
            
            if (result == true){
                //check for input in the table name textbox
                if(txtTableName.GetLineLength(0) == 0){
                    string errorBoxText = "Please enter a name for the table.";
                    string caption = "Error";

                    MessageBox.Show(errorBoxText, caption, MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
                    return;
                }
                
                //create save dialog box for .db file
                //create output file
                Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog sdg = new Microsoft.Win32.SaveFileDialog();
                sdg.FileName = "databaseName";
                sdg.DefaultExt = ".db";
                sdg.Filter = "SQLite3 Database File (.db)|*.db";
                Nullable<bool> saveResult = sdg.ShowDialog();
                if (saveResult == true){
                    string saveFileName = sdg.FileName;
                    string cs = string.Format("URI=file:{0}", saveFileName);
                    string tableName = txtTableName.Text;
                    int i = 0;
                    #region SQLite logic
                    #region create table                    
                    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs)){
                        con.Open();
                        using (SQLiteCommand cmd = new SQLiteCommand(con)){
                            cmd.CommandText = string.Format(@"CREATE TABLE {0} (Timestamp INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, LeftHipState INTEGER NOT NULL, LeftHipX REAL, LeftHipY REAL, LeftHipZ REAL, LeftKneeState INTEGER NOT NULL, LeftKneeX REAL, LeftKneeY REAL, LeftKneeZ REAL, LeftAnkleState INTEGER NOT NULL, LeftAnkleX REAL, LeftAnkleY REAL, LeftAnkleZ REAL, LeftFootState INTEGER NOT NULL, LeftFootX REAL, LeftFootY REAL, LeftFootZ REAL, RightHipState INTEGER NOT NULL, RightHipX REAL, RightHipY REAL, RightHipZ REAL, RightKneeState INTEGER NOT NULL, RightKneeX REAL, RightKneeY REAL, RightKneeZ REAL, RightAnkleState INTEGER NOT NULL, RightAnkleX REAL, RightAnkleY REAL, RightAnkleZ REAL, RightFootState INTEGER NOT NULL, RightFootX REAL, RightFootY REAL, RightFootZ REAL, LeftKneeFlexion REAL, LeftKneeValgus REAL, RightKneeFlexion REAL, RightKneeValgus REAL)", 
                            txtTableName.Text); 
                                    Console.WriteLine(cmd.CommandText);                            
                            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        }
                        con.Close();
                    }
                    #endregion
                    using (SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(cs)){
                        DataTable table = new DataTable(tableName);
                                              
                        #region create columns                       
                        table.Columns.Add("Timestamp", System.Type.GetType("System.String"));
                            //------------------------------------------------------------------
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftHipState", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftHipX", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftHipY", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftHipZ", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftKneeState", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftKneeX", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftKneeY", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftKneeZ", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftAnkleState", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftAnkleX", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftAnkleY", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftAnkleZ", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftFootState", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftFootX", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftFootY", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftFootZ", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
                        table.Columns.Add("RightHipState", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightHipX", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightHipY", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightHipZ", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightKneeState", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightKneeX", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightKneeY", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightKneeZ", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightAnkleState", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightAnkleX", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightAnkleY", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightAnkleZ", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightFootState", System.Type.GetType("System.Int32"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightFootX", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightFootY", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightFootZ", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        //-------------------------------------------------------------------
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftKneeFlexion", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("LeftKneeValgus", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightKneeFlexion", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        table.Columns.Add("RightKneeValgus", System.Type.GetType("System.Double"));
                        
                        #endregion

                        var output = new List<MyData>();
                    
                        foreach (var line in File.ReadAllLines(inputFilePath)){
                            output.Add(new MyData(line.Split(',')));
                        }

                        foreach (MyData outputLine in output){
                            DataRow row = table.NewRow();  
                            row["Timestamp"] = outputLine.Time;
                            row["LeftHipState"] = outputLine.HlState;
                            row["LeftHipX"] = outputLine.HLX;
                            row["LeftHipY"] = outputLine.HLY;
                            row["LeftHipZ"] = outputLine.HLZ;
                            row["LeftKneeState"] = outputLine.KlState;
                            row["LeftKneeX"] = outputLine.KLX;
                            row["LeftKneeY"] = outputLine.KLY;
                            row["LeftKneeZ"] = outputLine.KLZ;
                            row["LeftAnkleState"] = outputLine.AlState;
                            row["LeftAnkleX"] = outputLine.ALX;
                            row["LeftAnkleY"] = outputLine.ALY;
                            row["LeftAnkleZ"] = outputLine.ALZ;
                            row["LeftFootState"] = outputLine.FlState;
                            row["LeftFootX"] = outputLine.FLX;
                            row["LeftFootY"] = outputLine.FLY;
                            row["LeftFootZ"] = outputLine.FLZ;
                            row["RightHipState"] = outputLine.HrState;
                            row["RightHipX"] = outputLine.HRX;
                            row["RightHipY"] = outputLine.HRY;
                            row["RightHipZ"] = outputLine.HRZ;
                            row["RightKneeState"] = outputLine.KrState;
                            row["RightKneeX"] = outputLine.KRX;
                            row["RightKneeY"] = outputLine.KRY;
                            row["RightKneeZ"] = outputLine.KRZ;
                            row["RightAnkleState"] = outputLine.ArState;
                            row["RightAnkleX"] = outputLine.ARX;
                            row["RightAnkleY"] = outputLine.ARY;
                            row["RightAnkleZ"] = outputLine.ARZ;
                            row["RightFootState"] = outputLine.FrState;
                            row["RightFootX"] = outputLine.FRX;
                            row["RightFootY"] = outputLine.FRY;
                            row["RightFootZ"] = outputLine.FRZ;
                            row["LeftKneeFlexion"] = outputLine.LKFX;
                            row["LeftKneeValgus"] = outputLine.LKVG;
                            row["RightKneeFlexion"] = outputLine.RKFX;
                            row["RightKneeValgus"] = outputLine.RKVG;

                            table.Rows.Add(row);
                            i++;
                            Console.WriteLine("{0}| {1} {2:N4} {3:N4} {4:N4}| {5} {6:N4} {7:N4} {8:N4}| {9} {10:N4} {11:N4} {12:N4}| {13} {14:N4} {15:N4} {16:N4}| {17} {18:N4} {19:N4} {20:N4}| {21} {22:N4} {23:N4} {24:N4}| {25} {26:N4} {27:N4} {28:N4}| {29} {30:N4} {31:N4} {32:N4}| {33:N2} {34:N2} {35:N2} {36:N2}\n",
                        outputLine.Time, outputLine.HlState, outputLine.HLX, outputLine.HLY, outputLine.HLZ, outputLine.KlState, outputLine.KLX, outputLine.KLY, outputLine.KLZ, outputLine.AlState, outputLine.ALX, outputLine.ALY, outputLine.ALZ, outputLine.FlState, outputLine.FLX, outputLine.FLY, outputLine.FLZ, outputLine.HrState, outputLine.HRX, outputLine.HRY, outputLine.HRZ, outputLine.KrState, outputLine.KRX, outputLine.KRY, outputLine.KRZ, outputLine.ArState, outputLine.ARX, outputLine.ARY, outputLine.ARZ, outputLine.FrState, outputLine.FRX, outputLine.FRY, outputLine.FRZ, outputLine.LKFX, outputLine.LKVG, outputLine.RKFX, outputLine.RKVG);
                        
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", i, table.Rows.Count);
                        string sql = string.Format("SELECT * FROM {0}", tableName);

                        using (SQLiteDataAdapter da = new SQLiteDataAdapter(sql, con)){
                            using (new SQLiteCommandBuilder(da)){
                                da.Update(table);
                            }
                        }                        
                        con.Close();
                    #endregion
                    }                             
                }
                #region

                //for input file
                //fileName = dlg.FileName;
                //OutputConsole.Text = " ";
                //OutputConsole.Text = fileName;
                //for output file
                //dataName = sdg.FileName;
                
            
#endregion
                
        } 
    }
          
    private void btnExit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        Environment.Exit(0);
    }

    private void btnInfo_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e){
        Environment.CurrentDirectory = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("windir");
        DirectoryInfo info = new DirectoryInfo(".");
        lock (info){
            OutputConsole.Text = String.Format("Directory info:    " + info.FullName);
        }
    }
}

    public class MyData{
        public MyData(string[] values){
            Time = int.Parse(values[0]);
            HlState = int.Parse(values[1]);
            HLX = double.Parse(values[2]);
            HLY = double.Parse(values[3]);
            HLZ = double.Parse(values[4]);
            KlState = int.Parse(values[5]);
            KLX = double.Parse(values[6]);
            KLY = double.Parse(values[7]);
            KLZ = double.Parse(values[8]);
            AlState = int.Parse(values[9]);
            ALX = double.Parse(values[10]);
            ALY = double.Parse(values[11]);
            ALZ = double.Parse(values[12]);
            FlState = int.Parse(values[13]);
            FLX = double.Parse(values[14]);
            FLY = double.Parse(values[15]);
            FLZ = double.Parse(values[16]);
            HrState = int.Parse(values[17]);
            HRX = double.Parse(values[18]);
            HRY = double.Parse(values[19]);
            HRZ = double.Parse(values[20]);
            KrState = int.Parse(values[21]);
            KRX = double.Parse(values[22]);
            KRY = double.Parse(values[23]);
            KRZ = double.Parse(values[24]);
            ArState = int.Parse(values[25]);
            ARX = double.Parse(values[26]);
            ARY = double.Parse(values[27]);
            ARZ = double.Parse(values[28]);
            FrState = int.Parse(values[29]);
            FRX = double.Parse(values[30]);
            FRY = double.Parse(values[31]);
            FRZ = double.Parse(values[32]);
            LKFX = double.Parse(values[33]);
            LKVG = double.Parse(values[34]);
            RKFX = double.Parse(values[35]);
            RKVG = double.Parse(values[36]);
        }

        public int Time { get; set; }
        public int HlState { get; set; }
        public double HLX { get; set; }
        public double HLY { get; set; }
        public double HLZ { get; set; }
        public int KlState { get; set; }
        public double KLX { get; set; }
        public double KLY { get; set; }
        public double KLZ { get; set; }
        public int AlState { get; set; }
        public double ALX { get; set; }
        public double ALY { get; set; }
        public double ALZ { get; set; }
        public int FlState { get; set; }
        public double FLX { get; set; }
        public double FLY { get; set; }
        public double FLZ { get; set; }
        public int HrState { get; set; }
        public double HRX { get; set; }
        public double HRY { get; set; }
        public double HRZ { get; set; }
        public int KrState { get; set; }
        public double KRX { get; set; }
        public double KRY { get; set; }
        public double KRZ { get; set; }
        public int ArState { get; set; }
        public double ARX { get; set; }
        public double ARY { get; set; }
        public double ARZ { get; set; }
        public int FrState { get; set; }
        public double FRX { get; set; }
        public double FRY { get; set; }
        public double FRZ { get; set; }
        public double LKFX { get; set; }
        public double LKVG { get; set; }
        public double RKFX { get; set; }
        public double RKVG { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Is it something subtle, or is it something that is actually wrong? I need to fix both the row count problem and the shifting data types.

Here's the XAML code for the `MainWindow`, so you don't have to reproduce it:

```
<Window x:Class="C_Sharp_SQLite_Testbed.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid Background="LightGray">
        <Button x:Name="btnLoad" Content="Load CSV File to Database" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,258,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="153" Click="btnLoad_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnExit" Content="Exit" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="312,258,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="btnExit_Click"/>
        <TextBlock x:Name="OutputConsole" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Height="243" Width="497" Background="Black" Foreground="#FF00E800" FontFamily="Lucida Console"/>
        <Button x:Name="btnInfo" Content="Directory Information" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="168,258,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="139" Click="btnInfo_Click"/>
        <TextBox x:Name="txtTableName" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="23" Margin="200,285,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120"/>
        <Label Content="Enter name for table in database:" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,282,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

The type of project is a console project, so you'll need to set that after opening up a new WPF project.

Perhaps a silly question to go along with this: would the amount of time I wait to open one of these files after writing it matter at all?

Comment: ... anyone? Any ideas?

Comment: How sure are you that you're checking the number of rows correctly? I ran your code and got 134 rows in the db each time it ran. I used sqlite-manager to check the data https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/ it ran in a few seconds on my PC, so as long as you're not killing the process while it's inserting there's no reason I see that all the rows shouldn't be there.

Comment: I'm using both the wxSQLite+ program I mentioned, and looked at the raw file size in Windows Explorer. It tended to vary.

Comment: You're using the sqlite-netFx40-setup-bundle-x86-2010-1.0.86.0.exe from here? http://system.data.sqlite.org/index.html/doc/trunk/www/downloads.wiki I also ran it as an x86 application in VS 2010. Do you have a zip file of your project?

Comment: I'm running the SQLite package available from NuGet. I found it's easier to do that way.

Comment: [The zip you requested](http://ec2-54-245-125-124.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com/csharpsqlitetestbed.zip). Please let me know when you have downloaded it so that I may remove the link.

Comment: downloaded and ran, same result, it inserts 134 rows

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31336/discussion-between-krtrego-and-aaron-mcruer)

Comment: Sounds like a capital idea, chum.

Comment: Are you available sometime today? Sorry, I'm relatively new to the chat feature and wasn't around when you started the room.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is the code posted here is correct, the problem with fewer rows is from exiting the application before the inserts are done.

The issue with the integers showing up as decimals was due to the tool being used to view the SQLite file, not the actual database itself.